# How to Edit address using X++ in AX 2012

Tags: x++, dynamics-ax-2012, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I have a address filled corresponding to a Customer record in AX 2012. Now, My requirement is to Select Address from Address tab of a Edit Customer form and then to update the same using X++ Code.. I have tried to perform below code after passing current Party and Location ID..

```
obj_DirParty = DirParty::constructFromPartyRecId(obj_partyTable.RecId );    
obj_DirParty.createOrUpdatePostalAddress(obj_postalAddress, formRun.purposecon());
```

But it is throwing error saying...

> Microsoft Dynamics AX Views are read only.

So ultimately I have to press ESC button to disallow changes, however a new record is being added in a DirpartyPostalAddressView and I am able to see my changes before pressing ESC in a form. But after pressing ESC, changes being made to LogisticsLocation table record changes to previous data.

My question is: how to avoid this error so I can get my updated data in a form.

Comment: Ensure that you are not attempting to update fields from a View buffer.  It will let you make changes to the field but I can't remember what event causes the 'error' to appear, even though you may not be calling insert() or update().

Comment: @ian_scho Before performing above code I have passed Current record of a Dirpartypostaladdress view to obj_postalAddress as obj_postalAddress = _args.recod;. Is that causing error? But if i will not pass current record then how it will check to update or to insert new address?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have AX2012 in front of me.  Perhaps obj_postalAddress is being modified before you pass it in as a parameter to the method?  I've don't recall passing a view as a parameter for args.record([VIEW])...  Perhaps it should only be a table buffer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa659195(v=ax.50).aspx

Comment: Thinking about it, the Args object will be serialised and de-serialised between application objects.  I very much doubt I could pack() and unpack() a view, but never tried it!

Comment: @ian_scho wel Let me put everything what I did there.... first of all I have one form from where I have to update Current. I have created menuitem for that form and placed it on the address tab of Edit Customer form, after that I set the datasource of a form as Dirpartypostaladdress.Now, On the init of my form.. I have written code as: obj_postalAddress = _args.record();
                intpartyid = obj_postalAddress.Party;
                intLocationId = obj_postalAddress.Location;. Then passed some parameters as: obj_postalAddress.CountryRegionId = "AUS";Finally wrote above 2 lines of code